# How does one say "Count to 10" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How do I ask someone to count to 10 in Esperanto? By that, I want him to say "1", then "2", then "3" ... up until "10". Is there a word or a sentence for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either say "*Nombru ĝis dek*" or "*Kalkulu ĝis dek*". I personally prefer to use "*nombri*" rather than "*kalkuli*" for 'to count', as the main meaning of "*kalkuli*" is 'to calculate', so that it can sometimes lead to misunderstandings (though not in this sentence).

Answer (score 4):

You would ask them: "Kalkulu ĝis dek."

- "Mi jam scias kalkuli ĝis dek kaj skribi" - *La Faraono*
- "Ŝafo kalkulita ne estas savita." - *Proverbaro Esperanta*

Comment: Isn't "kalkuli" for mathematical operations, such as 237+932=?

Comment: Yes, it can mean count or calculate (work out a mathematical operation) depending on context.

Comment: In Mazi en Gondolando, Corvax asks the gardener to "kalkuli" the trees and then he starts saying "unu… du…" etc.

Comment: The point in Mazi is the result: how many trees there are ("count the trees", not "count to ten").  To me the original question is about passing time (e.g. in hide-and-seek to give time for the players to hide themselves), so you not _kalkulu ĝis dek_ but _nombru_ or even _listigu ĝis dek_.